# Using shinyFiles: a shiny app where the user selects a file for download, then selects where to copy

Tags: r, shiny

The below code succesfully allows the user to browse and select a file. However I am unable to write the syntax for the download of this file.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage( 

  shinyFilesButton('files', label='File select', title='Please select a file', multiple=T) ,

  verbatimTextOutput('rawInputValue'),

  verbatimTextOutput('filepaths') ,

  downloadButton("downloadFiles", "Download Files")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  roots =  c(wd = 'H:/')

  shinyFileChoose(input, 'files', 
                  roots =  roots, 
                  filetypes=c('', 'txt' , 'gz' , 'md5' , 'pdf' , 'fasta' , 'fastq' , 'aln'))

  output$rawInputValue <- renderPrint({str(input$files)})

  filepathsObject <- renderPrint({parseFilePaths(roots, input$files)})

  output$filepaths <- filepathsObject

  output$downloadFiles <- downloadHandler(

    filename = 'filepathsObject' ,

    content = function(file) {
      file.copy(filepathsObject, file)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the file with `downloadHandler` you need to provide the full name including the path as a string, but your variable `filepathsObject` is an object of class `"shiny.render.function`.

The `parseFilePaths` function will return a list with all the information needed, but you need convert it to character. Below is you code modified to download the previously uploaded file.

Please note that the download button doesn't works well on the RStudio viewer, so launch the app in a browser if you want to have the original file name as default.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage( 
  shinyFilesButton('files', label='File select', title='Please select a file', multiple=T) ,
  verbatimTextOutput('rawInputValue'),
  verbatimTextOutput('filepaths') ,
  downloadButton("downloadFiles", "Download Files")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  roots =  c(wd = 'H:/')

  shinyFileChoose(input, 'files', 
                  roots =  roots, 
                  filetypes=c('', 'txt' , 'gz' , 'md5' , 'pdf' , 'fasta' , 'fastq' , 'aln'))

  output$rawInputValue <- renderPrint({str(input$files)})

  output$filepaths <- renderPrint({parseFilePaths(roots, input$files)})

  output$downloadFiles <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      as.character(parseFilePaths(roots, input$files)$name)
    },
    content = function(file) {
      fullName <- as.character(parseFilePaths(roots, input$files)$datapath)
      file.copy(fullName, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: I was exploring using the shinySaveButton, perhaps it is more streamlined. This meaning that it may work in one shot instead of the shinyFilesButton + download handler